# Nth root as value inside the root symbol is less than 1

Tags: limits, roots, decimal-expansion

$$L:=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x^{a}=0~~~~~~~~~~~\left(a>0\right)$$

As$~a\geq1~$, it is quite obvious for me that the above limit converges to zero.

The current problem for me is that$~a<1~$

For instance as we fix$~a=10^{-4}~$

$$x^a=x^{10^{-4}}=x^{\frac{1}{10^{4}}}$$

$$=\sqrt[10^{4}]{x}$$

$$f\left(x\right):=\sqrt[10^{4}]{x}$$

What I want to prove is that for$~0<x_{\text{small}}<x_{\text{big}}~$, the following is satisfied.

$$\color{blue}{\sqrt[10^{4}]{x_{\text{small}}}<\sqrt[10^{4}]{x_{\text{big}}}}$$

For simplicity, I assume$~x_{\text{small}},x_{\text{big}}=10^{-9},10^{-3}~$respectively.

So, of course,$~f\left(x\right)~$indicates the value of piece which is powered by$~10^{4}~$is$~x~$

$$\sqrt[10^{4}]{10^{-9}},\sqrt[10^{4}]{10^{-3}}$$

$$\text{Assumption}~\rightarrow~10^{-t}:=\sqrt[10^{4}]{10^{-9}}$$

$$\text{Assumption}~\rightarrow~10^{-u}:=\sqrt[10^{4}]{10^{-3}}$$

$$10^{-t}=\left(10^{-9}\right)^{\frac{1}{10^{4}}}$$

$$=10^{-\frac{9}{10^{4}}}$$

$$\therefore~~t=\frac{9}{10^{4}}~,~u=\frac{3}{10^{4}}$$

\begin{equation*}%uasge:&smth\\. . Dont write symbol of line break at the end of row
 \begin{cases}
 10^{-t}=10^{-\frac{9}{10^{4}}}\\
 10^{-u}=10^{-\frac{3}{10^{4}}}\\
 \end{cases} 
\end{equation*}

My brain has panicked at here.

How can I proceed?

Comment: If $a>0$, then the function $f(x)=x^{a}$ is increasing for $x >0$. You can see this by taking the derivative $f'(x) = a x^{a-1} > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed positive $a$ the function given by
$$
f(x) = x^a
$$
is a continuous  increasing function of $x$, with $f(0) = 0$. One way to see that is to note that its derivative
$$
f'(x) = ax^{a-1} > 0
$$
for $x > 0$.

The fact that $a-1 < 0$ when $a < 1$ means that the graph of $f$ is tangent (from the right) to the $y$-axis at the origin. So the slope is badly behaved there, but the function itself has limit $0$.

Look at the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ to see what is going on.